# Azure Synapse TSQL

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am new to Azure Synapse and had a question about how the files are setup on Azure while creating an external table from a select. Would the files be over-written or would one need to truncate the files every time a create external table script is run? For e.g. if I run the following script

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[PopulationCETAS] WITH (
        LOCATION = 'populationParquet/',
        DATA_SOURCE = [MyDataSource],
        FILE_FORMAT = [ParquetFF]
) AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'csv/population-unix/population.csv',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'sqlondemanddemo',
        FORMAT = 'CSV', PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) WITH (
        CountryCode varchar(4),
        CountryName varchar(64),
        Year int,
        PopulationCount int
    ) AS r;
```

Would the file created

```
LOCATION = 'populationParquet/',
        DATA_SOURCE = [MyDataSource],
        FILE_FORMAT = [ParquetFF]
```

be overwritten every time the script is run? Can this be specified at the time of setup or within the query options?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to be able to drop the files in storage with a DELETE or TRUNCATE operation but this feature doesn’t currently exist within T-SQL. Please [vote for this feature](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/fb5a00c9-0a25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).

In the meantime you will need to use outside automation like an Azure Data Factory pipeline.